# Autocompletion doesn't suggest dynamic function parameters

Tags: typescript

I built a utility function to make web service calls. The types for this function look like the following:

```
type Apis = {
  service: {
    // list of all possible functions to the web server
    increment: (req: {value: number}) => Promise<number>
  }
}
function executeApi<TParam extends {}, TResult>(webFunction: (apis: Apis) => ((param: TParam) => TResult), param: TParam): TResult
```

In my code I can use this function

```
executeApi((apis) => apis.service.increment, { value: 2 });
```

The first parameter describes which method should be called. The second parameter is used as a parameter for the function from parameter one.

The problem is that the autocompletion of the second parameter does not work correctly. It can be reproduced in VS-code or online on the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAghAlgZxgXhgb2DGyoBOAbogMZQBcWOuMiAdqQVALZT0hUAUzAjlZiIBDADYBXSjHpiWAI0IBfAJToAfDAAKBAPYsUUADzS5hVTQXALwAGZjGIRNvowoADyikxIKAkQGAKhpCBEIsLq7e9AAmqJgKADQw-gBKUMhiIiCqXADuULIAYnakDk7cQkjIVL7IKmjqXFwQwaFUgS0sdeopaRkgSonNISxtQcNKbanpmdS4zCBiBM55hcWl9FzSIiIwQqhC9GBKTR1KANyWwDZrjs4MTKzsIABMPFD8WMLiksbyBMpYeaLZxbHZ7XaHM5WNweLw%20JCNCooLq7SoAOnwxDIUDR92YbA4iTi52AMM83l8jRReMeHGeROUZyAA)

If i use a function not from the apis parameter, everything works as expected:

In the following screenshot, the autocompletion isn't working
[image: the autocompletion isn't working]

In the following screenshot, the autocompletion is working
[image: the autocompletion is working]

I built a utility function to make web service calls. The types for this function look like the following:

```
type Apis = {
  service: {
    // list of all possible functions to the web server
    increment: (req: {value: number}) => Promise<number>
  }
}
function executeApi<TParam extends {}, TResult>(webFunction: (apis: Apis) => ((param: TParam) => TResult), param: TParam): TResult
```

In my code I can use this function

```
executeApi((apis) => apis.service.increment, { value: 2 });
```

The first parameter describes which method should be called. The second parameter is used as a parameter for the function from parameter one.

The problem is that the autocompletion of the second parameter does not work correctly. It can be reproduced in VS-code or online on the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAghAlgZxgXhgb2DGyoBOAbogMZQBcWOuMiAdqQVALZT0hUAUzAjlZiIBDADYBXSjHpiWAI0IBfAJToAfDAAKBAPYsUUADzS5hVTQXALwAGZjGIRNvowoADyikxIKAkQGAKhpCBEIsLq7e9AAmqJgKADQw-gBKUMhiIiCqXADuULIAYnakDk7cQkjIVL7IKmjqXFwQwaFUgS0sdeopaRkgSonNISxtQcNKbanpmdS4zCBiBM55hcWl9FzSIiIwQqhC9GBKTR1KANyWwDZrjs4MTKzsIABMPFD8WMLiksbyBMpYeaLZxbHZ7XaHM5WNweLw%20JCNCooLq7SoAOnwxDIUDR92YbA4iTi52AMM83l8jRReMeHGeROUZyAA)

If i use a function not from the apis parameter, everything works as expected:

In the following screenshot, the autocompletion isn't working
[image: the autocompletion isn't working]

In the following screenshot, the autocompletion is working
[image: the autocompletion is working]